# Usage of the verb FRESCO

Tags: word-usage

Can the verb **fresco** be used to describe **points out** or **represents**, or this verb can only be used to describe **paint in fresco**.

Example:

The President **frescoes** the innovative suggestion during his inaugural speech.

If it can be used in the context of the above sentence, would it sound awkward to the English native speaker?

Comment: it sounds strange to me - as a verb it means "to paint using fresco" (possibly "to wetly/freshly paint", "to quickly/rapidly paint", based on the technique's nature)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find 'fresco' as a verb in either Cambridge or Websters dictionaries, but it seems to be in use as a verb for the act of creating a fresco.

In your example, it is clearly being used figuratively. Fresco is art painted onto fresh (still wet) plaster. It seems the writer has used this as an illustration because the president took a new (fresh) idea and immortalised it by including it in such a momentous speech as his inauguration.

You asked if it sounds awkward to a native speaker - well, I had to go to the dictionary. But that is the advantage of written text over spoken - you can take time to think about analogies, and that can sometimes have more of an impact. I think it would be lost on many in everyday speech.